# Can I say 'they have no favour of that thing'?

Tags: vocabulary

If group of people born to be really tall, and someone begins compliment them. How can I say that thier height is not something they worked for it and did thier best about it?
Can I say: they have no credit? Or, they have no favour?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could say 'they can take no credit for their height' but not 'no favour for it'.